# How to reverse numbers in a list

Tags: java, input, stack

I have a code that first takes an integer from a scanner and then breaks it down into digits and then stores them in a list:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int date = in.nextInt();
    LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    while (date > 0) {
        stack.push( date % 10 );
        date = date / 10;
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
```

I was wondering if there is any other way to reverse the order of numbers other than using stacks.

Comment: can i get an explanation on the down vote? for future improvements

Comment: Not my down vote but I'd say that you didn't do your own research first.

Comment: `I was wondering if there is any other way` Read input as String; reverse that String; convert the reversed String to int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse a list in-place using [`Collections.reverse(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29).